# Bot framework Task modules takes a lot of time for first load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am invoking the task module from the bot. It takes a lot of time around 15 seconds for the first load. Although the subsequent loads are faster.
Is there a way to make the first load faster ?

My code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Reserve a Space</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/msteams-16.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Site.css" />

    <script src="./js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/microsoftTeams.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="surface theme-light">
    <div id="reserveSpace" class="panel panel-override"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            reservableBuildings: [],
          };

          this.makeReservation = this.makeReservation.bind(this);
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
          const {
            instanceURL,
          } = this.state;

          microsoftTeams.initialize();
        }

        async makeReservation() {
            microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(
              reservationResponse,
              "app Id"
            );
            return true;
          }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
                Some code
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("reserveSpace"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anything i make to optimize the first load.

Comment: Is it every time used that it is slow? Or, only after awhile of inactivity that it is slow? If the latter, please check that your app service configuration is set to 'Always on'. This keeps your service (i.e., bot) from going to sleep when inactive. This is usually the issue.

Comment: @StevenKanberg , it is everytime 1st time load is slow. From second time since it is caching the resources , it is fast. But, it is slow every first load. Yes, the app service configuration is already set to "Always on" . And the issue is only with the task modules not with any other component of the BOT.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If so, can you update your post to also include your manifest.json file used for setting up your bot in Teams?

Comment: Are you still stuck with this issue ?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT it is still an issue for us. First load is significantly longer for task modules only.